# Android quiz game add image questions into SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am building a quiz game using SQLite database.  at the moment the questions are displayed in text, I want to use image as a question. click on "image example" below to see what I mean.  the image on the left is how my application is now however I want to make it like the image on the right. how can I do it?

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCyAv.jpg)

This is what database looks like

```
package com.example.sqz;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuizHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;// constant for version of database

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SQZ.db";// constant for database name
private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";// constant for table name

// constant for identifying table and columns
private static final String KEY_ID = "questionid";
private static final String COL_QUES = "question";
private static final String COL_ANSWER = "answer"; // correct answer
private static final String COL_ANSWER1 = "ANSWER1"; // answer 1
private static final String COL_ANSWER2 = "ANSWER2"; // answer 2
private static final String COL_ANSWER3 = "ANSWER3"; // answer 3
private static final String COL_ANSWER4 = "ANSWER4"; // answer 4
private static final String LEVEL = "LEVEL";

private SQLiteDatabase mydbase;

public QuizHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    mydbase = db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + COL_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + COL_ANSWER1 + " TEXT, "
            + COL_ANSWER2 + " TEXT, " + COL_ANSWER3 + " TEXT, " + COL_ANSWER4 + " TEXT, "+ LEVEL+ " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    addQuestion();
    // db.close();
}

private void addQuestion() {
    Question q1 = new Question("Which team won FIFA world cup in 2002 ?", "Brazil", "England","Germany", "Italy", "Brazil",1);
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2 = new Question("How many goals Messi scored UEFA Champions League 2015  ?", "7", "6", "5", "8", "6",1);
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3 = new Question("Which team won cricket world cup in 2015  ?", "Australia", "England","New Zealand", "South Africa", "Australia",1);
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4 = new Question("Which team won premier league in 2015  ?", "Arsenal", "Manchester city", "Liverpool", "Chelsea", "Chelsea",1);
    this.addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5 = new Question("What team does LeBron James play for ?", "Cleveland Cavaliers", "Charlotte Hornets", "Los Angeles Clippers", "Miami Heat", "Cleveland Cavaliers",1);
    this.addQuestion(q5);
    Question q6 = new Question("Who scored the most goals in 2013  ?", "Lionel Messi", "Zlatan Ibrahimovic", "thierry henry", "Cristiano Ronaldo", "Cristiano Ronaldo",1);
    this.addQuestion(q6);
    Question q7 = new Question("Which team won world twenty20 in 2012  ?", "Australia", "West Indies", "South Africa", "Sri Lanka", "West Indies",1);
    this.addQuestion(q7);
    Question q8 = new Question("Who won Formula 1 championship in 2013  ?", "Fernando Alonso", "Sebastian Vettel", "Esteban Gutierrez", "Lewis Hamilton", "Sebastian Vettel",1);
    this.addQuestion(q8);
    Question q9 = new Question("Who won world darts championship in 2015 ?", "Gary Anderson", "Phil Taylor", "Boris Koltsov", "Michael van Gerwen", "Gary Anderson",1);
    this.addQuestion(q9);
    Question q10 = new Question("Cristiano Ronaldo played for which team in 2007  ?", "Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Man United", "Man United",1);
    this.addQuestion(q10);
    Question q11 = new Question("how many goals Steven gerrard has scored for liverpool ?", "186", "195", "188", "174", "186",1);
    this.addQuestion(q11);
    Question q12 = new Question("Steve Smith plays for which cricket team  ?", "England", "New Zealand", "South Africa", "Australia", "Australia",1);
    this.addQuestion(q12);
    Question q13 = new Question("How many goals Neymar scored for Santos   ?", "137", "136", "140", "138", "136",1);
    this.addQuestion(q13);
    Question q14 = new Question("Steven Finn plays for which cricket team  ?", "England", "New Zealand", "South Africa", "Australia", "England",1);
    this.addQuestion(q14);
    Question q15 = new Question("Which football team Wayne Rooney play for  ?", "Man City", "Liverpool", "Man United", "Arsenal", "Man United",1);
    this.addQuestion(q15);
    Question q16 = new Question("Which tennis player was ranked number 1 in 2016  ?", "Roger Federer", "Tomas Berdych", "Novak Djokovic", "Rafael Nadal", "Novak Djokovic",1);
    this.addQuestion(q16);
    Question q17 = new Question("Who won Wimbledon Championships  ? 2013", "Roger Federer", "Tomas Berdych", "Novak Djokovic", "Andy Murray", "Andy Murray",1);
    this.addQuestion(q17);
    Question q18 = new Question("Which team won FIFA world cup in 2014   ?", "Spain", "Germany", "Brazil", "Italy", "Germany",1);
    this.addQuestion(q18);
    Question q19 = new Question("Which team won twenty20 cricket in 2009  ?", "Pakistan", "Indian", "England", "Sri Lanka", "Pakistan",1);
    this.addQuestion(q19);
    Question q20 = new Question("Which team won cricket world cup in 2007  ?", "India", "Sri Lanka", "New Zealnad", "Australia", "Australia",1);
    this.addQuestion(q20);
    Question q21 = new Question("Who won tour de france 2014  ?", "Bradley Wiggins", "Leopold Konig", "Vincenzo Nibali", "Alberto Contador", "Vincenzo Nibali",1);
    this.addQuestion(q21);

    // END
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);// Drop older table if existed

    onCreate(db); // Create another table
}

// Adding new question
public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
    // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
    values.put(COL_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
    values.put(COL_ANSWER1, quest.getA1());
    values.put(COL_ANSWER2, quest.getA2());
    values.put(COL_ANSWER3, quest.getA3());
    values.put(COL_ANSWER4, quest.getA4());
    values.put(LEVEL, quest.getLevel());

    // Inserting Row
    mydbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
}

public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    mydbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mydbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question quest = new Question();
            quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setASWR1(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setASWR2(cursor.getString(4));
            quest.setASWR3(cursor.getString(5));
            quest.setASWR4(cursor.getString(6));



                questionList.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return quest list
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        list.add(i);

    Collections.shuffle(list, new Random());

    List<Question> shuffledQuestionList = new ArrayList<Question>();


    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        shuffledQuestionList.add(questionList.get(list.get(i)));



    return shuffledQuestionList;

}

public List<Question> getAllQuestionsByLevel(int level) {
    List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST+" where "+LEVEL+" ='"+String.valueOf(level)+"'";
    mydbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mydbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question quest = new Question();
            quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setASWR1(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setASWR2(cursor.getString(4));
            quest.setASWR3(cursor.getString(5));
            quest.setASWR4(cursor.getString(6));
            quest.setLevel(cursor.getInt(7));

            if(quest.getLevel()==level)
                questionList.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return questionList;
    // return quest list
    //ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     //   list.add(i);
  ///  Collections.shuffle(list);
//    List<Question> shuffledQuestionList = new ArrayList<Question>();


//      for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
//            shuffledQuestionList.add(questionList.get(list.get(i)));


    //return shuffledQuestionList;

}



}
```

Comment: For the hint you can store image's name in database, And retrieve image if necessary based on file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options if you want to keep everything offline:

1. Store image name (or a hint) to database and then load image from resource based on name into a new image view and nest it into a question container.
2. Convert image to base64 (basically text representation), and store it to database as text. And once you get it convert back to bitmap and set bitmap drawable to new image view then nest it into a question container.

Comment: Are there any tutorial  available to watch or read. as I am new to coding, I need to go through them to understand first, I tried looking up but could not find much information?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing the images online on a server and then in the database you have a URL pointing to the correct image. If you want the images to be stored on your local device you can cache them during the start up off you application. Simply look for the database links and download each one locally. Having them hosted online also gives you the flexibility to either cache them locally or just simply displaying them on the go.

Edit: You can of course just add all the images to the assets folder and then just add a pointer in the database to point to the correct image. This solution is completely offline.